# PHP works in Dreamweaver but fails to run on Browser

Tags: php, windows, iis, dreamweaver

My PHP code runs in  dreamweaver and also connect to the database, but my problems is when I run the same file on my local browser it wants do download the file and the PHP code does not run.

Comment: Are you accessing the file through the filesystem? i.e. the address bar will look like `C:\website\index.php`

Comment: do you have http server running with php support ? like wamp ?

Comment: Install WAMP (or similar). You need a local server to run PHP

Answer (score 0):

PHP can only be processed on the server side. You will need to set up a web server to run that file.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language. It must be run in the same directory as you use in Dreamweaver. You can't copy the PHP file and expect it to work if it is in another directory.

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing the file through the filesystem?

i.e. the address bar will look like `C:\website\index.php`

If not then, this could be a problem with how you've set up the webserver (if at-all). Please post some more information about the server and I will update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is Server Sided scripting and the way to view this is to code your  scripts on DreamWeaver then view the newly created scripts locally by using a Apache/PHP Stack, which can be found in XAMPP

http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Install that, then navigate through to

> localhost or 127.0.0.1

through your web browser

The Webdirectory will be:

> C:\xampp\htdocs

If you do not configure something else during the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load in the "local browser" using the adress **http://localhost/youphpfilename.php**